Eloquent model relationship with where clause good idea
A project I've taken over creates relationships in a rather odd way that I've never seen done before.
consider one such example:
public function invites(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Invite::class,
        'user_invites',
        'id',
        'user_id'
    )->where('is_active', 1);
}

I have concerns for such code as Laravel doesn't seem to endorse such use and also phpstan raises concerns about it as well.
My question is, should I consider refactoring the code so the relationship isn't being setup this way or is this fine and I just need to tell phpstan to ignore this.

This approach is uncommon and maybe a little odd, and there are better ways to handle it (active/inactive scope, ad-hoc query, etc.), but curious why you think this is a concern? What issues does PHPStan say about this? If the use case for this code is that $model->invites should only ever reference records where is_active is true, and you really don't care about ones where is_active is false, then this code is perfectly valid

it doesn't like the return type hinting coming back, I've just told phpstan to ignore it as I'm guessing it's a bug with phpstan 2.0

I wonder if that is because the return type becomes \Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder when you use ->where(). (class BelongsToMany extends Relation and abstract class Relation implements BuilderContract). If you use Builder as the return type, then I think it'll make PHPStan happy. Though I've never used PHPStan.

Magnie's comment is correct; the type changes from a BelongsToMany (via return $this->belongsToMany()) to a Builder when you tack on the ->where() clause. public function invites(): Builder would indeed solve your issue

then phpstorm throws a fit lol, I can't win. I just ignored it as it's working and that's what matters the most.

Putting a where clause in the relationship function, while uncommon, doesn't seem to be discouraged in Laravel's documentation:
public function currentPricing(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->ofMany([
        'published_at' => 'max',
        'id' => 'max',
    ], function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('published_at', '<', now());
    });
}

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#advanced-has-one-of-many-relationships
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
                ->wherePivot('approved', 1);
 
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
                ->wherePivotIn('priority', [1, 2]);
 
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
                ->wherePivotNotIn('priority', [1, 2]);
 
return $this->belongsToMany(Podcast::class)
                ->as('subscriptions')
                ->wherePivotBetween('created_at', ['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-12-31 00:00:00']);
 
return $this->belongsToMany(Podcast::class)
                ->as('subscriptions')
                ->wherePivotNotBetween('created_at', ['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-12-31 00:00:00']);
 
return $this->belongsToMany(Podcast::class)
                ->as('subscriptions')
                ->wherePivotNull('expired_at');
 
return $this->belongsToMany(Podcast::class)
                ->as('subscriptions')
                ->wherePivotNotNull('expired_at');

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

that's good to know, I appreciate the answer.

This is fine
public function invites(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Invite::class,
        'user_invites',
        'id',
        'user_id'
    )->where('is_active', 1);
}

but this is better:
public function invites(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Invite::class,
        'user_invites',
        'id',
        'user_id'
    );
}

public function activeInvites(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->invites()->where('is_active', 1);
}

